# laravel blade - variable not defined

Tags: laravel

I have a table in my database called websites.

Inside it I have two fields:

name = with value "name"
html = (whole html code stored in that field)

So at the moment what I want to do is:

If I type into a browser localhost/website/name which is the variable from database and after I hit enter I want to display actual rendered html page from a field html assosiated to that name so it looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Template 1</title>
        <link href="http://localhost/templates/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo">
        <img class="images" id="image" src="#" alt="Your Logo"/>
    </div>
<div  contenteditable="true" id="content" class="draggable ui-widget-content refresh"><p>Change Text inside this box</p></div>

<div id ="editTxt" class="refresh" contenteditable="true">
<p>This text can be by the user.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously I don't want to see the code but the actual page. How can that be done?

website.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master') @section('title', 'Website Builder') @section('content')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />


{{html_entity_decode($website->html)}}


</html>
@endsection @show
```

Route:

```
Route::get('website/{name}', 'BuilderController@websites');
```

Controller:

```
function websites($name)
{
    $websites = Website::find($name);
    return view('layouts/website');
}
```

And current error message (assuming this code will display the page if this error is fixed)

> Undefined variable: website (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fyproject\resources\views\layouts\website.blade.php)

So basically value 'name' => 'null' and in my database it isn't so why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the variable to the view to fix this:

```
$websites = Website::find($name);
return view('layouts/website', ['websites' => $websites]);
```

Or:

```
$websites = Website::find($name);
return view('layouts/website', compact('websites'));
```